# Binary search in Python not working properly, only displaying some items in list

Tags: python, list, search, counter

My code isn't working properly and is only displaying the correct results of 3 items and not the one in the 2nd index. I wouldn't have posted but I went from the pseudocode given on the GCSE bitesize page for CS which isn't working when I convert in Python. 
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zm77xfr/revision/3

```
my_list=['arnold', 'matt', 'david', 'james']

found = False
search_item = input("type a name to find")
start_range = 0
end_range = len(my_list)



while found == False and start_range <= end_range:
    mid = (start_range + end_range) //2

    if search_item == my_list[mid]:
        found == True
        print("item found")
    else:

        if my_list[mid] >= search_item:
            end_range = mid -1
        else:
            start_range = mid +1


if found == False:
    print("item not found")
```

When I run the code above and type in 'arnold', I get an 'item found' message printed infinitely which is fine for now. However, if I type in the second item from the list, in this case 'matt', I get an 'item not found' message display

If I type in 'david' or 'james' it works as well, so it's only the item in the 2nd index.

I initially converted the GCSE bitesize pseudocode in python but it didn't even work. I'm really confused, I have no clear idea to why it's not working but have a feeling it has something to do with the index or even the mid variable.

Could someone direct me on which part to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few issues here that needed to be addressed. First of all, binary search requires the list to be sorted, so that the comparisons (ie `my_list[mid] >= search_item`) make sense.
Next, you need to change `found == True` to `found = True`. The way you have it is just a comparison, not setting the value to `True`.

It should look like this:

```
my_list=['arnold', 'matt', 'david', 'james']

found = False
search_item = input("type a name to find")
start_range = 0
end_range = len(my_list) - 1

# ADD THIS
my_list.sort()

while found == False and start_range <= end_range:
    mid = (start_range + end_range) //2

    if search_item == my_list[mid]:
        # CHANGE THIS
        found = True
        print("item found")
    else:

        if my_list[mid] >= search_item:
            end_range = mid -1
        else:
            start_range = mid +1

if found == False:
    print("item not found")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess that's a disadvantage of a binary search that the list has to be sorted but then again it can be done with one line of code. Your answer is perfect and the code works well now.